# Is the data the requests library sends secure in python?

Tags: python, http, https, python-requests

Say I want to send a username and password as the payload of a POST request. Would that username and password be secure/encrypted like with HTTPS, or is it just sent as plain text, and therefore unsecure?

Comment: @goalie1998 So if the URL I am making the request to is HTTPS, then the data sent is encrypted? Likewise, if the URL is HTTP, then the data sent is plaint text?

Comment: Yes, exactly, as explained in the duplicate link. Its not up to your code to implement encryption. As long as you make sure to target https, then it should be fine.